# Stop sign in notification area instead of language icon

Tags: gnome, language-support, icons

I have a "stop sign" instead of a language icon in my notification area. How can I fix it?

It also a stop sign instead of a language icon in the login window after suspend

Comment: What icon theme are you using?

Comment: What happens if you click on that icon? What do you call "language icon", is that the keyboard selector?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you set the option (in gconf) to use "flags" to indicate the current keyboard layout when there are no flag icons installed (there are none by default).

Comment: Ok, so where one should put an icon? And how should it be called?